# How to unset session data by page number upto n pages in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('current_page_'.$pagenumber);
```

by using this code i am unsetting data from session for each page number but the issue is at certain point i do not know how many pages data exist in session e.g:

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('current_page_'.1);
$this->session->unset_userdata('current_page_'.2);
$this->session->unset_userdata('current_page_'.3);
$this->session->unset_userdata('current_page_'.4);
.
.
.
$this->session->unset_userdata('current_page_'.?????);
```

is there any way to unset data from session where key like "current_page_%"
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `current_page` as the name and then only store the actual page number in the session? `$this->session->set_userdata('current_page', $page_no);`

Comment: in $page_no it will b array?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, in the case of an array you can always serialize the data first: `$this->session->set_userdata('current_page', serialize($array));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try searching the initials **(which is `current_page_`)** of the session and unset accordingly.

```
<?php
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    // search backwards starting from haystack length characters from the end
    return $needle === "" || strrpos($haystack, $needle, -strlen($haystack)) !== FALSE;
}

foreach($this->session->all_userdata() as $key => $value)
{
    if(startsWith($key, 'current_page_'))
        $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
}
```

**For example:**

```
<?php
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    // search backwards starting from haystack length characters from the end
    return $needle === "" || strrpos($haystack, $needle, -strlen($haystack)) !== FALSE;
}

$session = array(
            'current_page_12' => 'abc', 
            'current_page_qw1' => 'xyz', 
            'hello' => 'world', 
            'current_page_23d' => 'mno', 
            'example' => '112'
        );

foreach($session as $key => $value)
{
    if(startsWith($key, 'current_page_'))
        unset($session[$key]);
}

print_r($session);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [hello] => world
    [example] => 112
)
```

**Demo:**
http://3v4l.org/uh4HK

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$j = 1;
for($i=0;$i==$j;$i++)
{
    if($this->session->userdata('current_page_'.$i))
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('current_page_'.$i);
        $j++;
    }else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a problem in this as i dont know which page number exist e.g

Comment: ok for that you should use array like instead of doing this current_page_1, current_page_2 etc you should use current_page[1],current_page[2] etc.

Answer (score 0):

This statement will print all session data and from this you can get all page numbers.

print_r($this->session->all_userdata());

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(Here I simply use [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to get all array elements which follows the pattern. To match the keys and not the values I use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get all keys. And then I just loop trough the matches with a foreach loop and unset the array elements)

```
<?php


    //As an example v Here just use your array
    $array = array("current_page_1" => 1, "current_page_1345" => 2, "current_page_12" => 3, "current_page_34" => 4, "xy" => 5, "z" => 6);
    $sub = preg_grep("/(current_page_)\d+/", array_keys($array));

    foreach($sub as $v)
        unset($array[$v]);  //$this->session->unset_userdata($v);

    print_r($array);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [xy] => 5 [z] => 6 )
```

Comment: how much time ll it take then?

Comment: @pakistanimoon What do you mean with *how much time ll it take* ? Like how long the script has to execute ?

Comment: i just wanted that will ot b more faster than other solutions given by other users here?

Comment: @pakistanimoon I just compared mine with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28556912/3933332 and both are pretty much the same speed with 10k array elements. Between 0.02 - 0.03 secs to execute. Just choose the answer and the script which you think helped you the most and solved your problem